# Android Wear : Wearable Not recognized by Eclipse

Tags: android, wear-os

I am working on Android wear SDK in Eclipse,

I am unable import below line of code,

```
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Node;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.NodeApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;
```

I also added google play services library to the build path, Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Eclipse has been depreciated for android development, I suggest you use Android Studio..

Comment: Have you Install API 20 In AndroidSDK??